# validar dato repetido antes de procesar un ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

Estoy usando struts 2 y ajax. El problema es cuando quiero evitar que se ingrese un dato repetido a mi base de datos.

Este es el codigo, me valida el primer objeto del array, pero cuando ingreso el segundo valor repetido, me deja registrar.

```
function grabarHerramienta(){
var json,nom,sto,mon,pre,fec,ser,tip;

nom = $("#idNombre").val();
sto = $("#idStock").val();
mon = $("#idMoneda:checked").val();
pre = $("#idPrecio").val();
fec = $("#idFecha").val();
ser = $("#idSerie").val();
tip = $("#idTipo").val();

json = JSON.stringify({
    nombre:nom,
    stock:sto,
    moneda:mon,
    precio:pre,
    fecha:fec,
    serie:ser,
    codTipoHerramienta:tip
});


$.get("listarHerramientas",{}, function(response){
    $.each(response.listaHerramientas, function(index, item){
        if (nom == item.nombre){
            console.log("Ya existe");
            return false;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'guardarHerramienta',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {JSONHerramienta:json},
                success:function(data){
                    if (data.dataMensaje == 1){
                        console.log(data);
                        mostrarHerramienta();
                        $("#exampleModal").modal("hide");
                    } else {
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })
})
```

Me registra , pero no quiero que ingrese el mismo valor.

Answer (score 0):

EL problema esta que `nom` lo verificas con el elemento actual de tu recorrido del ciclo y debería verificarse con todos los elementos de tu respuesta. ya que cuando empieza el recorrido si no es igual lo va insertar siempre.

Ejemplo:

```
var existe=false;
$.get("listarHerramientas",{}, function(response){
    $.each(response.listaHerramientas, function(){
        if (nom == this.nombre){//hay que convertir a mayúsculas o minúsculas las comparaciones por difieren en ello, ademas si trae espacios aplicarle trim
            console.log("Ya existe");
            existe=true;//si lo encuentra termina el recorrido y asigna true
            return;
        } 
    })
});
if(existe==false)//si no encontró alguna  igualdad con la colección response.listaHerramientas, realiza la petición
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'guardarHerramienta',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {JSONHerramienta:json},
        success:function(data){
            if (data.dataMensaje == 1){
                console.log(data);
                mostrarHerramienta();
                $("#exampleModal").modal("hide");
            } else {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Igual me deja registrar con el mismo nombre

Comment: revisa si  en tu $.each lo esta encontrando

Comment: en el $.each si me recorre y lo encuentra, pero una vez que lo encuentra sigue el recorrido y me registra.